# MARKLOGIC: Is it possible to use more than 1 columns from a CSV file when generating URI ID during data ingestion in MarkLogic?

Tags: csv, uri, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-dhf

I am quite new to MarkLogic and I am not sure how to best deal with the challenge I have right now.

I have a CSV file exported from a table that will be ingested to MarkLogic database. Now the source table uses 4 columns as its unique primary key combination.

In MarkLogic, by default, only one column from CSV file can be used as the URI ID.

My question is, is it possible to use more than 1 columns from a CSV file as the URI ID during data ingestion in MarkLogic?
If yes, is this feature or setting available in data hub?
If it is not possible, what is usually the best practice for this in MarkLogic?

I know that one possible work around is to create a new column combining the data from 4 primary key columns and use it as the URI ID.

Comment: Just to be clear. You are describing MLCP above and not MarkLogic itself. Geert described to you the perfect bridge between the two worlds.

Comment: I think he merely meant MarkLogic Data Hub where he mentioned MarkLogic.. ;)

Comment: Either way, your example (Geert) is the bridge between client side processing (MLDH or MLCP whatever) and Server Side processing (where the actual transform of the document is taking place prior to insertion into the database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MLCP Transforms](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518) to transform both the content value, and the uri. It gets a hash object $content containing both. Update its values as desired, and return the updated hash object. Something like:

```
declare function example:transform(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map
) as map:map*
{
  let $record := map:get($content, "value")
  let $uri := $record/prop1 || $record/prop2 || $record/prop3 
  let $_ := map:put($content, "uri", $uri)
  return $content
};
```

You can use such MLCP transforms in marklogic-data-hub as well.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, grtjn! Do you know how or where exactly to use MLCP transforms in Marklogi-data hub? Currently, the Transform Options field in my Data-Hub UI is currently disabled in Input-Flows.

Comment: On second thought, it seems data-hub applies its own transform, and you can only apply one. You may need to use -generate_uri to get all records in, and then use harmonize to get them in the right shape.

Comment: There is also a ticket related to this, but it was closed. Feel free to comment there too: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-data-hub/issues/182